# create gaps between spline points with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, splines

Following this answer  [curve intersection with volume in animation nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/curve-intersection-with-volume-in-animation-nodes/119645?noredirect=1#comment209613_119645), I've managed to create a spline which i use to distribute objects inside a volume.

Here is how:

[image]

But I still need to avoid having distributed objects along the spline when this one gets outside the volume along the gap
:[image]

How can it be done? I've tried substracting those points (outside volume) from the ones that are generating the spline that is used to distribute the objects but as it now look obvious the spline will still be generated. So my second option is to do it inside the distribution objects loop but don't know how, any ideas?
[image]

EDIT

AS @Omar Ahmad proposes finding inside points is straight forward using BVHTREE but this way we cant control the distance between the volume faces and the points.[image]

EDIT 2

@Omar Ahmad solution does the job but putting the tool to some tricky situations give inconsistent results like this ones:

[image]
[image]

I'll be trying the other solution proposed, far more complex, which I'm already struggling to replicate.

Comment: Do you plan to animate either curve or volume, and if yes, how should the points behave then? E.g. If the gap increases, would the drawn points move closer together or would some of them suddenly disappear? And would the number of intersections stay constant or is it variable?

Comment: Neither curve o volume are going to be animated but as I'm building this a tool for "parametric object placing" everything should be updated anytime something changes. The tool should work like this:  from a list of objects I need to distribute them along an spline EVENLY only through the segments which are inside a given volume. All objects in this list (which can vary in length) have to be distributed and cannot be just hidden. Please ask if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will be using the technique described in my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/curve-intersection-with-volume-in-animation-nodes/#answer-119958). After getting the parameters of the intersections, we prepend it with zero and append it with 1 representing the start and end of the spline respectively. The prepended list represents the starting parameters of the sub-splines between intersection points while the appended list represents the ending parameters. We can generate those sub-splines by trimming as follows:

[image: Sub-Spline]

We can then loop over the sub-splines, evaluate a point in the middle and see if it is inside the object or not, if yes, we append the spline:

[image: Interior Splines]

And that is it, you now have the interior splines which you can evaluate to get what you want. For instance:

[image: Example]

Comment: the problem with this method is that I don't have control over the distances between the intersection of the spline with the volume and the points.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch Edited the answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy. Your solution does the job but after putting it into some stress situations I get inconsistent results. Check my edit. I'm going to try @binweg approach.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch There might be a better simpler approach to all this, but it may not be as straightforward as the method we have been using. Will write an answer soon.

Comment: Oh that would be great, this solutions may not be perfect but just taking the time to reproduce and understand them is giving me so much knowledge, thanks. I´ll try my own approach also

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch May we know what is not perfect about this new solution?

Comment: my apologies, I was answering your first comment(from 20h ago). I'm reading your new answer right now

Comment: due to some problems with your original method (which I answered he [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/curve-intersection-with-volume-in-animation-nodes) I'm not able to reproduce your solution

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch Did you manage to make it work? Do you want me to upload a file for you to inspect?

Comment: Well that is just perfect, the question has been answered. The file is not necessary I prefer to reproduce it myself so I can at least try to understand what I'm doing.  But may ask one more thing? Right now each interior spline is distributing the same amount of points in between, is it posible to give a fixed number of points to be shared between those splines? so given a distance factor if there is not enough space for a certain number of points it jumps to the next one

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch Sure, compute the length of each sub-spline $L_i$ and add them to get a total length $L_t$, lets say you want to distribute $N$ points in total, so you write a ratio to compute the number of points to distribute on each sub-spline $n$:
$$
\frac{L_i}{L_t} = \frac{n}{N}
$$
Giving you the equation $n = \frac{L_i \cdot N}{L_t}$ where $n$ is the number of points for each sub-spline, $L_i$ is the length of the sub-spline and $L_t$ the total length of all sub-splines.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it myself. Don`t know what I would have done without your help

Comment: Its been a while since I implemented this method into my workflow and new issues have emerged using this solution. Everything works as expected right now just as it was  explained but only if the intersecting Spline is made up of two control points. Right now I'm building the splines from mesh objects so they are filled up with control points, this produces weird artifacts, is there a way around to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at this problem is quite similar to [Omar Ahmad's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119770/34236) in that I calculate the spline parameter of the intersections – i.e. their positions along the spline's length in the range of zero to one – and use this value for the placement.

[image: result]
(Visible hollow copy only for demonstration purposes. Origial filled box used for calculations is hidden)

As a first step, I modify the *Raycast* loop of the [node tree for the intersections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119645/34236) to return the *parameter* and a boolean that gives information about the angle of normal and segment, and through that, whether the intersection is an entry into or an exit from the volume. In my setup, `False` means entry and `True` means exit.
The additional parameter *spline length* comes from a *Get Spline Length* node of the spline.

[image: modified raycast]

With an expression node `list(zip(x, y))` I convert the two lists into one list of pairs, one for each intersection. For example

```
[(False, 0.2),
 (True,  0.5),
 (False, 0.6),
 (True,  0.9)]
```

To handle the spline's ends, I check for the first and the last point on the spline whether they are in the volume (*BVH Tree > Is Inside Volume*) and add a expression that will later interpret these points as additional entries or exits.
If there is always at least one intersection, one could invert the first and last boolean of the list, but checking *Is Inside Volume* also works when there is no intersection.

[image: add start and end]

This will end up as something like this:

```
[(True,  0),
 (False, 0.2),
 (True,  0.5),
 (False, 0.6),
 (True,  0.9)
 (False, 1)]
```

Similarly to the two slices `vectors[:-1]` and `vectors[1:]` in the tree to find the intersections, I create two slices `tuples[:-1]` and `tuples[1:]` and feed them into another loop.

[image: tuple slices]

The *Create Splines* loop checks whether each segment is inside of the volume based on the supplied boolean values, adjust the parameters of start and end by a given value to “prevent” (in some cases) the objects to appear directly at the wall or even clip into it, and check whether the adjusted segment is even long enough to hold any object.

[image: create spline loop]

While Omar Ahmad at this point continues to work with the parameters, I return a trimmed copy of the original spline (iff the spline is inside the volume and the segment is long enough).

The list of splines is fed into a final loop *sample splines*, along with a float number to set the average number of items to place per unit. From the loop's *Evaluate Spline* node we can extract location, tangents for the rotation etc.

[image: sample splines loop]
[image: place some objects]

Using the segments' length and the ceiling function gives a rather regular distribution of objects, but it complicates things if you want a fixed number of objects. Maybe algorithms commonly used to assign seats to politicians after elections like the [Sainte-Laguë method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster/Sainte-Lagu%C3%AB_method) can be used, considering the lengths of the segments. Or you simply tweak the average until you're happy with the total. :P

The number of placed objects depends on the length of the segments:
[image: offset gap]

The distance of the first objects from each wall, or the average number of objects per unit can be adjusted, though the distance from a wall is calculated along the spline and might be misleading (a.k.a. wrong) for shallow angles:
[image: more items and more space from wall]
[image: shallow angles]

As mentioned above, the node tree should work for no intersections as well. For splines completely enclosed in the volume (with objects) or splines completely outside (no objects):
[image: no intersection]

Unfortunately, it won't work for cyclic splines.

N.B.: By default, the resolution of the *Evaluate Spline* nodes, which can be set in the advanced node settings in the properties panel of the node, is quite low. This resulted in an uneven distribution for me. Increasing the resolution solved this problem.

My .blend file for Animation Nodes v2.1:
[image]

Comment: this is huge! Ok I'm trying to replicate your solution, I even updated to v2.1, but as some of the nodes are collapsed  is taking me a wile. For instance the "create pairs node" is self explicatory but somehow I cant find any vector list operation with two outputs.

Comment: My fault, sorry. *Create Pairs* is a group of the two list slices `[:-1]` and `[1:]` that also appeared in the *find intersections* node tree. I initially grouped them as I intended to reuse the group on the right. But that didn't look as good as originally thought as there was a type mismatch (Vector List vs Generic List) that would have required additional *Convert Type* nodes. I forgot to get rid of the node group.

Comment: I noticed your two additional test cases and might add, that this answer also doesn't work for zero-width gaps, or more than one intersection per original segment. For the second test case, this might also have to to with the resolution of the Evaluate Spline nodes that I mentioned. Failing the first test case might be avoidable by not using *Ray Cast* but instead checking whether start and/or end of the segment are inside the volume (which could be done for both Omar Ahmad's solution as well as mine).

Comment: even if this one was not the perfect solution it did what it was asked and  also shares a big amount of knowledge, Im will also accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but apart from the variable number of objects in my answer, which is also implementable in the other answer, I too think that Omar Ahmad's answer is the superior one and I wouldn't mind if you accepted that answer. Props when it's due :)