# Find the Intersection between a curve and a sphere in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I have Splines starting at a random vector inside of a sphere. I want to find the point on the Surface of the sphere where the sphere and the splines intersect.

The blue markings are the starting points of the splines. They are positioned randomly inside of the spline. The splines follow a vector field and almost never intersect the sphere at the closest surface point.

Is there a better (more performant) way to do this, that looping through all the points of the spline, finding the one before and after the intersection (by checking the distance of the points to the closest surface point or something similar) and then using the intersect line sphere node?

[image]

Comment: maybe this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/curve-intersection-with-volume-in-animation-nodes

Comment: Thats pretty much my approach. and if omar doesnt have a better solution, there probably isn't one. So it helps, thanks. Not sure why this question didnt pop up though.